# Android OpenGLES 2 ray picking, resulting coordinate jumpy in certain spots?

Tags: java, android, 3d, camera, transformation

I am trying to implement object picking based on touch coordinates via an intersecting ray test. 
I am having trouble finding information on converting the touch coordinates to the coordinate system used in the world in order to construct this ray.

My understanding so far is that the matrix that is applied to each vertex in the scene is:

```
projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix
```

Here is my process for reversing that process in a an attempt to find the ray's endpoint in the scene as well as my drawing loop in case I'm simply applying the different matrices incorrectly:

```
    public float[] getMouseRayProjection(float touchX, float touchY, float windowWidth, float windowHeight, float[] modelView, float[] projection)
        {
        float[] rayDirection = new float[4];

        float normalizedX = 2 * touchX/windowWidth - 1;
        float normalizedY = 1 - 2*touchY/windowHeight;

        float[] unviewMatrix = new float[16];
        float[] viewMatrix = new float[16];
        Matrix.multiplyMM(viewMatrix, 0, projection, 0, modelView, 0);
        Matrix.invertM(unviewMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);

        float[] nearPoint = multiplyMat4ByVec4(projection, new float[]{normalizedX, normalizedY, 0, 1});
        float[] modelviewInverse = new float[16];
        Matrix.invertM(modelviewInverse, 0, modelView, 0);

        float[] cameraPos = new float[4];
        cameraPos[0] = modelviewInverse[12];
        cameraPos[1] = modelviewInverse[13];
        cameraPos[2] = modelviewInverse[14];
        cameraPos[3] = modelviewInverse[15];

        rayDirection[0] = nearPoint[0] - cameraPos[0];
        rayDirection[1] = nearPoint[1] - cameraPos[1];
        rayDirection[2] = nearPoint[2] - cameraPos[2];
        rayDirection[3] = nearPoint[3] - cameraPos[3];

        return rayDirection;
        }

    public float[] multiplyMat4ByVec4(float[] matrix4, float[] vector4)
        {
        float[] returnMatrix = new float[4];

        returnMatrix[0] = (matrix4[0] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[1] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[2] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[3] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[1] = (matrix4[4] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[5] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[6] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[7] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[2] = (matrix4[8] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[9] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[10] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[11] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[3] = (matrix4[12] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[13] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[14] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[15] * vector4[3]);

        return returnMatrix;
        }



@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 10000L;

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, (int)(width/2), (int)(height/2));
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 2f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    drawTriangle(triangleVertices);
    drawIntersectionLine();

    //Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 1.5f, 0, -1f);
    //Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
    //Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 1.5f, 0.8f, 0.5f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    GLES20.glViewport((int)(width/2), (int)(height/2), (int)(width/2), (int)(height/2));
    drawTriangle(triangleVertices);
    drawIntersectionLine();


    //Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0, 2f, 1f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1f);
    GLES20.glViewport((int)(width/2), 0, (int)(width/2), (int)(height/2));
    drawTriangle(triangleVertices);
    drawIntersectionLine();
}

private void drawTriangle(final FloatBuffer triangleBuffer)
{
    triangleBuffer.position(positionOffset);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, positionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, strideBytes, triangleBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    triangleBuffer.position(colorOffset);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, colorDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, strideBytes, triangleBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

private void drawIntersectionLine()
{
    lineVertices.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, positionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, lineStrideBytes, lineVertices);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, 3);
}

private void moveIntersectionLineEndPoint(float[] lineEndPoint)
{
    this.lineEndPoint = lineEndPoint;

    float[] lineVerticesData = {
        lineStartPoint[0], lineStartPoint[1], lineStartPoint[2],
        lineEndPoint[0], lineEndPoint[1], lineEndPoint[2]
    };
    lineVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lineVerticesData.length * bytesPerFloat).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    lineVertices.put(lineVerticesData).position(0);
}
```

Although I'm pretty sure my 4x4 matrix by 4d vector multiplication method is correct, here is that method as well just in case:

```
public float[] multiplyMat4ByVec4(float[] matrix4, float[] vector4)
    {
        float[] returnMatrix = new float[4];

        returnMatrix[0] = (matrix4[0] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[1] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[2] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[3] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[1] = (matrix4[4] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[5] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[6] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[7] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[2] = (matrix4[8] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[9] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[10] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[11] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[3] = (matrix4[12] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[13] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[14] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[15] * vector4[3]);

        return returnMatrix;
    }
```

The goal of this test app is to show the scene from a few separate angles so that I can see how the intersection line looks based on my code. I wanted to draw the line starting at the camera's origin and ending at the intersection point, but it's acting oddly. The endpoint seems to be moving in accordance with the mouse for the most part, but in some spots it's seems to sort of...skip, as if there were a hole at that location or something. It's at those points that the returned numbers don't make sense and the mouse endpoint seems to shoot out in some random direction. Although I still remember a bit of linear algebra from calculus, I don't remember enough to know exactly what I'm doing here and I've scoured through many of the resources online with no luck. I'm hoping someone that reads this will have more experience dealing with this than I and will be kind enough to help me, or give me any tips if there's something else that I may be doing in an incorrect or inefficient way.

Variable Reference:
Matrices are all float arrays of length 16

```
mProjectionMatrix = projection matrix

mModelMatrix = model matrix

mMVPMatrix = projection * modelview matrix

mMVMatrix = modelview matrix


    private final FloatBuffer triangleVertices;

    private FloatBuffer lineVertices;

    private final int bytesPerFloat = 4;

    private float[] viewMatrix = new float[16];

    private static Context context;

    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    private int mPositionHandle;

    private int mColorHandle;

    private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] mMVMatrix = new float[16];

    private final int strideBytes = 7 * bytesPerFloat;
    private final int lineStrideBytes = 3 * bytesPerFloat;

    private final int positionOffset = 0;

    private final int positionDataSize = 3;

    private final int colorOffset = 3;

    private final int colorDataSize = 4;

    private float width, height;

    private float[] lineStartPoint = new float[]{0, 0, 1.5f};

    private float[] lineEndPoint = new float[]{0, 0, 0};
```

Just in case it helps to see the entirety of the class that handles graphics, here that is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;

public class OpenGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private final FloatBuffer triangleVertices;

    private FloatBuffer lineVertices;

    private final int bytesPerFloat = 4;

    private float[] viewMatrix = new float[16];

    private static Context context;

    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    private int mPositionHandle;

    private int mColorHandle;

    private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] mMVMatrix = new float[16];

    private int[] viewport = new int[4];

    private final int strideBytes = 7 * bytesPerFloat;
    private final int lineStrideBytes = 3 * bytesPerFloat;

    private final int positionOffset = 0;

    private final int positionDataSize = 3;

    private final int colorOffset = 3;

    private final int colorDataSize = 4;

    private float width, height;

    private float[] lineStartPoint = new float[]{0, 0, 1f};

    private float[] lineEndPoint = new float[]{0, 0, 0};

    public OpenGLRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        final float[] triangleVerticesData = {
                -0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

                0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

                0.0f, 0.559016994f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        };

        triangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangleVerticesData.length * bytesPerFloat).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        triangleVertices.put(triangleVerticesData).position(0);

        float[] lineVerticesData = {
            lineStartPoint[0], lineStartPoint[1], lineStartPoint[2],
            lineEndPoint[0], lineEndPoint[1], lineEndPoint[2]
        };
        lineVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lineVerticesData.length * bytesPerFloat).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        lineVertices.put(lineVerticesData).position(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        final float eyeX = 0.0f;
        final float eyeY = 0.0f;
        final float eyeZ = 2.5f;

        final float lookX = 0.0f;
        final float lookY = 0.0f;
        final float lookZ = -5.0f;

        final float upX = 0.0f;
        final float upY = 1.0f;
        final float upZ = 0.0f;

        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);

        try {
            int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

            if (vertexShaderHandle != 0)
            {
                GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, readShader("vertexShader"));

                GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);

                final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

                if (compileStatus[0] == 0)
                {
                    GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderHandle);
                    vertexShaderHandle = 0;
                }
            }

            if (vertexShaderHandle == 0)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating vertex shader");
            }

            int fragmentShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

            if (fragmentShaderHandle != 0)
            {
                GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, readShader("fragmentShader"));

                GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);

                final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

                if (compileStatus[0] == 0)
                {
                    GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
                    fragmentShaderHandle = 0;
                }
            }
            if (fragmentShaderHandle == 0)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating fragment shader.");
            }

            int programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

            if (programHandle != 0)
            {
                GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);
                GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);

                GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "a_Position");
                GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 1, "a_Color");

                GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);

                final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);

                if (linkStatus[0] == 0)
                {
                    GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programHandle);
                    programHandle = 0;
                }
            }

            if (programHandle == 0)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating program.");
            }

            mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
            mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");
            mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Color");

            GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "The shader could not be read: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", e.getMessage());
        }

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);
        GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width/2, height/2);

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        final float ratio = (float) width / height;
        final float left = -ratio;
        final float right = ratio;
        final float bottom = -1.0f;
        final float top = 1.0f;
        final float near = 1.0f;
        final float far = 10.0f;

        GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 10000L;

        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, (int)(width/2), (int)(height/2));
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 2f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        drawTriangle(triangleVertices);
        drawIntersectionLine();

        //Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 1.5f, 0, -1f);
        //Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
        //Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 1.5f, 0.8f, 0.5f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        GLES20.glViewport((int)(width/2), (int)(height/2), (int)(width/2), (int)(height/2));
        drawTriangle(triangleVertices);
        drawIntersectionLine();


        //Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0, 2f, 1f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1f);
        GLES20.glViewport((int)(width/2), 0, (int)(width/2), (int)(height/2));
        drawTriangle(triangleVertices);
        drawIntersectionLine();
    }

    private void drawTriangle(final FloatBuffer triangleBuffer)
    {
        triangleBuffer.position(positionOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, positionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, strideBytes, triangleBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        triangleBuffer.position(colorOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, colorDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, strideBytes, triangleBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }

    private void drawIntersectionLine()
    {
        lineVertices.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, positionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, lineStrideBytes, lineVertices);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, 3);
    }

    private void moveIntersectionLineEndPoint(float[] lineEndPoint)
    {
        this.lineEndPoint = lineEndPoint;

        float[] lineVerticesData = {
            lineStartPoint[0], lineStartPoint[1], lineStartPoint[2],
            lineEndPoint[0], lineEndPoint[1], lineEndPoint[2]
        };
        lineVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lineVerticesData.length * bytesPerFloat).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        lineVertices.put(lineVerticesData).position(0);
    }

    public static String readShader(String filePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(filePath)));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public float[] getMouseRayProjection(float touchX, float touchY, float windowWidth, float windowHeight, float[] modelView, float[] projection)
    {
        float[] rayDirection = new float[4];

        float normalizedX = 2 * touchX/windowWidth - 1;
        float normalizedY = 1 - 2*touchY/windowHeight;

        float[] unviewMatrix = new float[16];
        float[] viewMatrix = new float[16];
        Matrix.multiplyMM(viewMatrix, 0, projection, 0, modelView, 0);
        Matrix.invertM(unviewMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);

        float[] nearPoint = multiplyMat4ByVec4(unviewMatrix, new float[]{normalizedX, normalizedY, 0, 1});
        float[] modelviewInverse = new float[16];
        Matrix.invertM(modelviewInverse, 0, modelView, 0);

        float[] cameraPos = new float[4];
        cameraPos[0] = modelviewInverse[12];
        cameraPos[1] = modelviewInverse[13];
        cameraPos[2] = modelviewInverse[14];
        cameraPos[3] = modelviewInverse[15];

        rayDirection[0] = (nearPoint[0] - cameraPos[0]);
        rayDirection[1] = (nearPoint[1] - cameraPos[1]);
        rayDirection[2] = (nearPoint[2] - cameraPos[2]);
        rayDirection[3] = (nearPoint[3] - cameraPos[3]);

        return rayDirection;
    }

    /*
    public float[] getOGLPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        GLU.gluUnProject(x, y, 0, , modelOffset, project, projectOffset, view, viewOffset, obj, objOffset)
    }
    */

    public float[] getCameraPos(float[] modelView)
    {
        float[] modelviewInverse = new float[16];
        Matrix.invertM(modelviewInverse, 0, modelView, 0);
        float[] cameraPos = new float[4];
        cameraPos[0] = modelviewInverse[12];
        cameraPos[1] = modelviewInverse[13];
        cameraPos[2] = modelviewInverse[14];
        cameraPos[3] = modelviewInverse[15];
        return cameraPos;
    }

    public String floatArrayAsString(float[] array)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        for (Float f : array)
        {
            sb.append(f + ", ");
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public float[] getInverseMatrix(float[] originalMatrix)
    {
        float[] inverseMatrix = new float[16];
        Matrix.invertM(inverseMatrix, 0, originalMatrix, 0);
        return inverseMatrix;
    }

    public float[] multiplyMat4ByVec4(float[] matrix4, float[] vector4)
    {
        float[] returnMatrix = new float[4];

        returnMatrix[0] = (matrix4[0] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[1] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[2] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[3] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[1] = (matrix4[4] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[5] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[6] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[7] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[2] = (matrix4[8] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[9] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[10] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[11] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[3] = (matrix4[12] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[13] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[14] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[15] * vector4[3]);

        return returnMatrix;
    }

    public void onTouch(float touchX, float touchY)
    {
        float[] mouseRayProjection = getMouseRayProjection(touchX, touchY, width, height, mMVMatrix, mProjectionMatrix);
        Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "Mouse Ray: " + floatArrayAsString(mouseRayProjection));
        //Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "ModelView: " + floatArrayAsString(mMVMatrix));
        //Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "ModelViewInverse: " + floatArrayAsString(getInverseMatrix(mMVMatrix)));
        //Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "Mouse Coordinates: " + touchX + ", " + touchY);
        //Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "Ray Coordinates: " + mouseRayProjection[0] + ", " + mouseRayProjection[1] + ", " + mouseRayProjection[2] + ", " + mouseRayProjection[3]);
        moveIntersectionLineEndPoint(mouseRayProjection);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what library your using (I'm not familiar with Android), but it seems like you'd at least need to multiply your normalized point by the *inverse* of the projection matrix, at this line: `...multiplyMat4ByVec4(projection, new flo...`


Also, it seems like you're unsure of whether or not your matrices are row or column major, which matters when you're extracting values as a camera position.


Otherwise, the best way to debug this is to draw something at the position where you expect the ray end to be.

Comment: I've since changed that line to use the inverse of the view matrix that was calculated previously. Should I be using the projection matrix instead? As the movement of the endpoint of the intersection line is difficult to explain in words, here is a video documenting its behavior. Notice how even though the mouse is moving in a circular pattern, sometimes the end of the line will jump to a position that doesn't make sense and then continue to act normally. This behavior is not mirrored in the touch coordinates returned in the touch event.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lq3nB8TKMIc

Answer (score 2):

After some searching, I found a page that details this process in a different manner. Now I no longer have the issue with the end of the ray jumping to an unexpected position at random times and the end point points to the exact location it should!
Here is the page I used to fix my process:
http://www.antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html

And here is my final source code for the entire intersection testing app. Most of the relevant code is within the OpenGLRenderer class under the getMouseRayProjection method.

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MyGLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGLSurfaceView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);

        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        OpenGLRenderer renderer = new OpenGLRenderer(this);
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(renderer);
        mGLSurfaceView.renderer = renderer;

        setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
    }

}

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public OpenGLRenderer renderer;

    public float previousX, previousY;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        switch(e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float dx = x - previousX;
            float dy = y - previousY;

            renderer.onTouch(x, y);
        }

        previousX = x;
        previousY = y;
        return true;
    }
}
```

OpenGLRenderer.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;

public class OpenGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private final FloatBuffer triangleVertices;

    private FloatBuffer lineVertices;

    private final int bytesPerFloat = 4;

    private float[] viewMatrix = new float[16];

    private static Context context;

    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    private int mPositionHandle;

    private int mColorHandle;

    private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

    private float[] mMVMatrix = new float[16];

    private int[] viewport = new int[4];

    private final int strideBytes = 7 * bytesPerFloat;
    private final int lineStrideBytes = 3 * bytesPerFloat;

    private final int positionOffset = 0;

    private final int positionDataSize = 3;

    private final int colorOffset = 3;

    private final int colorDataSize = 4;

    private float width, height;

    private float[] lineStartPoint = new float[]{0, 0, 1f};

    private float[] lineEndPoint = new float[]{0, 0, 0};

    private float[] cameraPos = new float[]{0f, 0f, 2.5f};
    private float[] cameraLook = new float[]{0f, 0f, -5f};
    private float[] cameraUp = new float[]{0f, 1f, 0f};

    public OpenGLRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        final float[] triangleVerticesData = {
                -0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

                0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

                0.0f, 0.559016994f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        };

        triangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangleVerticesData.length * bytesPerFloat).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        triangleVertices.put(triangleVerticesData).position(0);

        float[] lineVerticesData = {
            lineStartPoint[0], lineStartPoint[1], lineStartPoint[2],
            lineEndPoint[0], lineEndPoint[1], lineEndPoint[2]
        };
        lineVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lineVerticesData.length * bytesPerFloat).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        lineVertices.put(lineVerticesData).position(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, cameraPos[0], cameraPos[1], cameraPos[2], cameraLook[0], cameraLook[1], cameraLook[2], cameraUp[0], cameraUp[1], cameraUp[2]);

        try {
            int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

            if (vertexShaderHandle != 0)
            {
                GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, readShader("vertexShader"));

                GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);

                final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

                if (compileStatus[0] == 0)
                {
                    GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderHandle);
                    vertexShaderHandle = 0;
                }
            }

            if (vertexShaderHandle == 0)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating vertex shader");
            }

            int fragmentShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

            if (fragmentShaderHandle != 0)
            {
                GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, readShader("fragmentShader"));

                GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);

                final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

                if (compileStatus[0] == 0)
                {
                    GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
                    fragmentShaderHandle = 0;
                }
            }
            if (fragmentShaderHandle == 0)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating fragment shader.");
            }

            int programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

            if (programHandle != 0)
            {
                GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);
                GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);

                GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "a_Position");
                GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 1, "a_Color");

                GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);

                final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);

                if (linkStatus[0] == 0)
                {
                    GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programHandle);
                    programHandle = 0;
                }
            }

            if (programHandle == 0)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating program.");
            }

            mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
            mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");
            mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Color");

            GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "The shader could not be read: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", e.getMessage());
        }

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);
        GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width/2, height/2);

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        final float ratio = (float) width / height;
        final float left = -ratio;
        final float right = ratio;
        final float bottom = -1.0f;
        final float top = 1.0f;
        final float near = 1.0f;
        final float far = 10.0f;

        GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 10000L;

        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, (int)(width), (int)(height));
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, cameraPos[0], cameraPos[1], cameraPos[2], cameraLook[0], cameraLook[1], cameraLook[2], cameraUp[0], cameraUp[1], cameraUp[2]);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        drawTriangle(triangleVertices);
        drawIntersectionLine();
    }

    private void drawTriangle(final FloatBuffer triangleBuffer)
    {
        triangleBuffer.position(positionOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, positionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, strideBytes, triangleBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        triangleBuffer.position(colorOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, colorDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, strideBytes, triangleBuffer);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }

    private void drawIntersectionLine()
    {
        lineVertices.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, positionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, lineStrideBytes, lineVertices);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINES, 0, 2);
    }

    private void moveIntersectionLineEndPoint(float[] lineEndPoint)
    {
        this.lineEndPoint = lineEndPoint;

        float[] lineVerticesData = {
            lineStartPoint[0], lineStartPoint[1], lineStartPoint[2],
            lineEndPoint[0], lineEndPoint[1], lineEndPoint[2]
        };
        lineVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lineVerticesData.length * bytesPerFloat).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        lineVertices.put(lineVerticesData).position(0);
    }

    public static String readShader(String filePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(filePath)));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public float[] getMouseRayProjection(float touchX, float touchY, float windowWidth, float windowHeight, float[] view, float[] projection)
    {
        float[] rayDirection = new float[4];

        float normalizedX = 2f * touchX/windowWidth - 1f;
        float normalizedY = 1f - 2f*touchY/windowHeight;
        float normalizedZ = 1.0f;

        float[] rayNDC = new float[]{normalizedX, normalizedY, normalizedZ};

        float[] rayClip = new float[]{rayNDC[0], rayNDC[1], -1f, 1f};

        float[] inverseProjection = new float[16];
        Matrix.invertM(inverseProjection, 0, projection, 0);
        float[] rayEye = multiplyMat4ByVec4(inverseProjection, rayClip);

        rayClip = new float[]{rayClip[0], rayClip[1], -1f, 0f};

        float[] inverseView = new float[16];
        Matrix.invertM(inverseView, 0, view, 0);
        float[] rayWorld4D = multiplyMat4ByVec4(inverseView, rayEye);
        float[] rayWorld = new float[]{rayWorld4D[0], rayWorld4D[1], rayWorld4D[2]};

        rayDirection = normalizeVector3(rayWorld);

        return rayDirection;
    }

    public float[] normalizeVector3(float[] vector3)
    {
        float[] normalizedVector = new float[3];
        float magnitude = (float) Math.sqrt((vector3[0] * vector3[0]) + (vector3[1] * vector3[1]) + (vector3[2] * vector3[2]));
        normalizedVector[0] = vector3[0] / magnitude;
        normalizedVector[1] = vector3[1] / magnitude;
        normalizedVector[2] = vector3[2] / magnitude;
        return normalizedVector;
    }

    /*
        public float[] getMouseRayProjection(float touchX, float touchY, float windowWidth, float windowHeight, float[] modelView, float[] projection)
        {
            float[] rayDirection = new float[4];

            float normalizedX = 2 * touchX/windowWidth - 1;
            float normalizedY = 1 - 2*touchY/windowHeight;

            float[] unviewMatrix = new float[16];
            float[] viewMatrix = new float[16];
            Matrix.multiplyMM(viewMatrix, 0, projection, 0, modelView, 0);
            Matrix.invertM(unviewMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);

            float[] nearPoint = multiplyMat4ByVec4(unviewMatrix, new float[]{normalizedX, normalizedY, 0, 1});
            float[] modelviewInverse = new float[16];
            Matrix.invertM(modelviewInverse, 0, modelView, 0);

            float[] cameraPos = new float[4];
            cameraPos[0] = modelviewInverse[12];
            cameraPos[1] = modelviewInverse[13];
            cameraPos[2] = modelviewInverse[14];
            cameraPos[3] = modelviewInverse[15];

            rayDirection[0] = (nearPoint[0] - cameraPos[0]);
            rayDirection[1] = (nearPoint[1] - cameraPos[1]);
            rayDirection[2] = (nearPoint[2] - cameraPos[2]);
            rayDirection[3] = (nearPoint[3] - cameraPos[3]);

            return rayDirection;
        }
     */

    /*
    public float[] getOGLPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        GLU.gluUnProject(x, y, 0, , modelOffset, project, projectOffset, view, viewOffset, obj, objOffset)
    }
    */

    public float[] getCameraPos(float[] modelView)
    {
        float[] modelviewInverse = new float[16];
        Matrix.invertM(modelviewInverse, 0, modelView, 0);
        float[] cameraPos = new float[4];
        cameraPos[0] = modelviewInverse[12];
        cameraPos[1] = modelviewInverse[13];
        cameraPos[2] = modelviewInverse[14];
        cameraPos[3] = modelviewInverse[15];
        return cameraPos;
    }

    public String floatArrayAsString(float[] array)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        for (Float f : array)
        {
            sb.append(f + ", ");
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public float[] getInverseMatrix(float[] originalMatrix)
    {
        float[] inverseMatrix = new float[16];
        Matrix.invertM(inverseMatrix, 0, originalMatrix, 0);
        return inverseMatrix;
    }

    public float[] multiplyMat4ByVec4(float[] matrix4, float[] vector4)
    {
        float[] returnMatrix = new float[4];

        returnMatrix[0] = (matrix4[0] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[1] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[2] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[3] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[1] = (matrix4[4] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[5] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[6] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[7] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[2] = (matrix4[8] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[9] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[10] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[11] * vector4[3]);
        returnMatrix[3] = (matrix4[12] * vector4[0]) + (matrix4[13] * vector4[1]) + (matrix4[14] * vector4[2]) + (matrix4[15] * vector4[3]);

        return returnMatrix;
    }

    public void onTouch(float touchX, float touchY)
    {
        float[] mouseRayProjection = getMouseRayProjection(touchX, touchY, width, height, mMVMatrix, mProjectionMatrix);
        Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "Mouse Ray: " + floatArrayAsString(mouseRayProjection));
        //Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "ModelView: " + floatArrayAsString(mMVMatrix));
        //Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "ModelViewInverse: " + floatArrayAsString(getInverseMatrix(mMVMatrix)));
        //Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "Mouse Coordinates: " + touchX + ", " + touchY);
        //Log.d("OpenGLES2Test", "Ray Coordinates: " + mouseRayProjection[0] + ", " + mouseRayProjection[1] + ", " + mouseRayProjection[2] + ", " + mouseRayProjection[3]);
        moveIntersectionLineEndPoint(mouseRayProjection);
    }
}
```

fragmentShader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
}
```

vertexShader:

```
uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;

attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Color;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main()
{
    v_Color = a_Color;
    gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if instead of downvoting a question, someone were to comment to explain why they were dissatisfied, so that I may at least attempt to help them. Simply downvoting the question does nothing to alleviate one's confusion, nor does it help others that might feel the same confusion, as the downvoting of the question forces it farther into the depths of stackexchange.